# pm2 creates more processes - cPanel Processes Limit reached

Tags: node.js, angular, cpanel, pm2

I'm using Cpanel to deploy an Angular Universal application. Before I used the command (node), it worked with few processes but when I switched to starting the application with pm2, many processes were launched that I reached the limit of cPanel processes.
Do you have a solution for this?
Thank you.